# Problems with deleting $_SESSION in PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm having a problem with deleting the session. It's stored in the cookies, and whenever I click on the log out button, nothing happens.

**HTML**

```
<input id="log_out_button" onclick="logout()" type="button" value="Log Out">
```

**AJAX**

```
function logout() {
    // Create request object 
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create event handler that specifies what should happen when server responds
    request.onload = function() {
        // Check HTTP status code
        if(request.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("error_messages").innerHTML = "";
        }
    else
        alert("Error communicating with server: " + request.status);
}
// Set up request with HTTP method and URL 
request.open("GET", "php/log_out.php");
//Send request
request.send();
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
//Start session management
session_start();

//Remove all session variables
session_unset(); 

//Destroy the session 
session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: Anything in your console error log? Is the logout() function ever getting executed?

Comment: Nothing appears on the console error log

Comment: But you don't do anything with `responseData` and nothing is returned from the php side.

Comment: I've removed it but still nothing happens

Comment: try redirecting to other page on success

Comment: I've also tried this, and nothing still happens

Comment: try `var_dump($_SESSION)` between each session command

Comment: what do you expect? up to your code if session is destroyed successfully you will now know that.

Comment: @User786 is there a semi-colon after the statement?

Comment: `Undefined variable: _SESSION` appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

so if you want to close user session, you also need to clear cookies

```
setcookie(session_name(), false, -1, '/');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: he says session stored in server is not deleted

Comment: @User786 session will restore if cookies are not deleted.
so you have to clear it if you want to close the session